# What causes pain when experiencing a static shock?

Tags: electricity, biophysics

What exactly causes the pain in my fingertip when I get a static shock from touching something?  Is it the current flowing through my nerves or is it a localized thermal burn from the spark itself?

Comment: I wonder whether this wouldn't be a better fit for [Biology.SE].

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree at this point. To OP, is there anything about the physics of static shock / interactions you are interested in? At the moment this does seem to be more of a biology question asking about the physiology that needs to be present to detect pain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 0):

It is the flow of tiny amounts of current through the nerve endings that creates the pain of a shock. The brevity of the (tiny) heat pulse is not detectable by your nerves unless the current is really big (which does not happen with shocks caused by static electric discharges)- which current might also be big enough to render you unconscious, in which case you probably will not experience (or remember) the pain or the heat flash.

There is a youtube video of a brown bear that climbed up a high-voltage power pole and before he could be rescued, shorted himself across two of the wires. At the instant this occurs, a flash of steam and smoke is blown out of his pelt as he falls unconscious to the ground. In this case, the heat pulse was sufficient to boil the water out of his hide, but not enough to kill him. By some miracle, he survived both the shock and the fall.